# Loading the MAMP PRO start page / MAMP start page

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mamp, mamp-pro

Ok, hope someone can help me out. I've installed MAMP PRO (after working with MAMP for a while).

When starting up MAMP PRO I’m connected to the Apache Server and MySQL. It’s working because I have both green lights, I can set up new servers and I can reach them too. I’ll get the following message, so I assume it’s working: “If you can see this page, your new virtual host was set up successfully.”

But what doesn’t work is that I can’t access my MAMP start page. So basically my `localhost:8888` page, where I can access my phpMyAdmin and see the Welcome message.

- The path to the root is correct: `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs`
- I've played around with the ports.
- I've installed MAMP PRO again (thought something went wrong with installing)

I'm actually able to get to the start page (and phpMyAdmin) through MAMP, but of course, that’s not what I want. I want to reach the page through MAMP PRO.

Answer (score 0):

To access the MAMPpro start page, just click on the top icon of your MAMP pro main window with the tag WebStart or insert the url 
`http://localhost:8888/MAMP/` in a browser.